# 3DNS share path issue in Windows

Tags: windows, dns, unc

3DNS name: **threednsname.eur.nsroot.net**

Above 3DNS points to 4 servers using a particular port. In whichever server, the port is up and running, the 3DNS will point to that server.

When we ping "ping threednsname.eur.nsroot.net" in command prompt, it points to correct server based on the server in which port id up.

Whereas the 3DNS share path "**//threednsname.eur.nsroot.net**" in File Explorer points to different servers(in those 4 servers) for different persons. It is inconsistent.

Could you please help resolving this 3DNS share path issue?

Comment: Could someone help regarding this?